Ensure that the key's associated value's type is a string
I am trying to "generate" the properties I need to upload an item to a database. For that, I have an interface, and then a mapping (keyof, string) which tells me the column name for each field of the interface.
Here is the code of the interface and mapping:
export interface HouseDetails {
    title: string;
    address?: string;
    price?: number;
    sq_meters?: number;
    comments?: string;
}

export type DatabaseMapping = Record<keyof HouseDetails, string>

And the code that uses the mapping:
type Property = {
    type: "rich_text",
    rich_text: string,
} | {
    type: "number",
    value: number,
}

function get_house_properties(dbm: DatabaseMapping, hd: HouseDetails): Record<string, Property> {
    function prop_rich_text(key: keyof HouseDetails): Record<string, Property> {
      // Is this avoidable?
      if (hd[key]) {
            return {
                [dbm[key]]: {
                    type: "rich_text",
                    rich_text: hd[key],
                }
            }
        } else {
            return {}
        }
    }

    return {
        // Should work
        ...prop_rich_text('address'),
        ...prop_rich_text('comments'),
        // Should compiler error
        ...prop_rich_text('price'),
    }
}

Because there are multiple fields of HouseDetails with the same "property type", I want to make some code that receives the key and generates the property. But it gives a type error because hd[key] might be a number and not a string.
TS2634: 'string' index signatures are incompatible.
  Type '{ type: "rich_text"; rich_text: string | number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Property'.
    Types of property 'rich_text' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How can I ensure that key is the key of a string?

Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] without undeclared or private things like CreatePageParameters.

I suppose you're looking for something like this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Fixed the question. About the playground link, yeah, that's exactly it! Feel free to put it as an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Instead of keyof HouseDetails, you want just those keys for which the property accepts a string value. There is no built-in TypeScript utility that works this way; there's a open issue at microsoft/TypeScript#48992 asking for that, but for now it's not part of the language.
Luckily you can write your own KeysMatchingForWriting<T, V> which evaluates to just those keys of T to which you can be guaranteed to write a value of type V (as opposed to those from which you can be guaranteed to read a value of type V).  Here's one possible way to do that:
type KeysMatchingForWriting<T, V> =
  keyof { [K in keyof T as [V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never]: any }

This is using key remapping to filter the properties to just those where [V] extends [T[K]]; that is, where you can assign V to the property of T at key K (the added brackets are there to avoid distributive conditional types).  Let's try it:
type StringHouseDetails = KeysMatchingForWriting<HouseDetails, string>;
// type StringHouseDetails = "title" | "address" | "comments"

Looks good. Note that if you did it the other way (T[K] extends V), for reading, you would not get address or comments because those are optional and therefore possibly undefined.  Anyway now you can use that instead of keyof HouseDetails and it works:
function get_house_properties(dbm: DatabaseMapping, hd: HouseDetails) {
  function prop_rich_text(
    key: KeysMatchingForWriting<HouseDetails, string>
  ): Record<string, Property> {
    if (hd[key]) {
      return {
        [dbm[key]]: { // okay
          type: "rich_text", rich_text: hd[key]
        }
      }
    } else { return {} }
  }
  return {
    ...prop_rich_text('address'), // okay
    ...prop_rich_text('comments'), // okay
    ...prop_rich_text('price'), // error
  }
}

Playground link to code

this doesn't prevent returning a number        [dbm[key]]: { type: "number", value: 1}

Does that matter? The return type is annotated as Record<string, Property>. Seems like that's out of scope for the question as asked.

imo yes, the output is actually narrowed also.

But they're not asking about that. They've specifically annotated the return type as Record<string, Property> and not Record<string, { type: "rich_text", rich_text: string, }>, and they didn't have an error there. It might be nice to do that, but it's not in scope for the question as it is asked. It's an aside at best here.

Yeah, that's out of scope, I wanted to keep the question simple.
